# how to pass java script values to controller using post method in .net core application?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I am developing .net core application.i need to pass java script values to my controller using Post method. i am using java script code is below

```
 data = {'imageValue':'some test'}
    $.ajax({ 
      type: 'Post',          
      url: '/Home/UploadData',      
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: data,
      success: function (data) {
      alert(data);      
      console.log('sample');                      
      },     
      error:  function(){
    }
    });
```

my controller is
 `[HttpPost]public string UploadData([FromBody] string imageValue)
        {return imageValue;}` but imageValue always it return null.if any mistake in my code please solve the problem.

Comment: what returns `null`? what is your expected behavior and what is happening now and when ?

Comment: Can you post the C# controller? I'd imagine you're missing the `[FromBody]` attribute

Comment: Do you sending correct json object from server side?

Answer (score 4):

When you make the ajax call, you should stringify the javascript object and send it. You can use the `JSON.stringify` method to convert the js object to it's JSON string equivalent.

```
var data = {'imageValue':'some test'}
$.ajax({
    type: 'Post',
    url: '/Home/UploadData',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (data) {

        console.log('sample', data);
    },
    error:  function(){
    }
});
```

Now since the ajax call is sending the data in the request body (since it is a POST request),You need to decorate the HttpPost action method parameter with [FromBody] attribute so that model binder knows it should read the data from the request body and map to the method parameter(*YourViewModel*) object.

```
public IActionResult UploadData([FromBody] YourViewModel d)
{
    return Json(d);
}
```